# How to get session variable in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I already set a session variable. I need Flash to be able to check if present and use it otherwise default to some value.

How can I do this in AS3?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the session data to Flash via FlashVars.

```
<object width="" height="">
    <param name="flashvars" value="sessionVar=sessionValue" />
    <embed src="file.swf?sessionVar=sessionValue" width="" height="" />
</object>
```

And pull them out in AS3:

```
var embedData:Object = root.loaderInfo.parameters;
// Access via embedData.sessionVar
```

Alternatively you could set up a PHP script that holds the session variables and then request them in AS3 using URLLoader.

Comment: I need to get values through session variables and not using flash vars. I can control the HTML code (only the SWF file).

Comment: @Martin There is no way to access session variables without pushing them to the SWF (imagine the security nightmares if my SWF could pull any session info that I wanted from its host).

Comment: Understand. Is is possible to do this with cookies instead?

Comment: @Martin: You may call a php script ( say GetSession.php) via as3, and can get the session value. But anybody may get  the link to this php file by peeping inside the swf. :|

Answer (score 1):

If it's a Javascript variable, you could use this actionscript code:

```
var sessionValue:String = ExternalInterface.call(String(<script>function(){ return sessionValue; };</script>));
trace("sessionValue:" + sessionValue); // output to debug window
```

If you want to read a javascript cookie from Flash, you could try to use this (untested)

```
trace("cookie 'sessionValue':" + readCookie("sessionValue")); // output to debug window

function readCookie(name:String):String { // quickly ported from http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html
 var nameEQ:String = name + "=";
 var cookie:String = ExternalInterface.call(String(<script>function(){ return document.cookie; };</script>));
 var ca:Array = cookie.split(';');
 for(var i:int = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c:String = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
 }
 return null;
}
```

In order to have ExternalInterface available, it should run online inside a browser, and `allowscriptaccess` should be `true` in the flash embed-code.

**More info:**
Flash ExternalInterface : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6
Javascript cookies :  http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html